# Change background url of div via HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (CSS - height: 250px, width: 70%) and I have set a background via CSS. I want to change the background onhover.

That's simple, I know. But I want to get sources of backgrounds from the HTML tag.

Ex.:

```
<div class="somediv" data-imgbefore="img1.png" data-imgafter="img2.png"></div>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: Show us what you tried ?

Comment: I do not know where to start actually... Nothing goes on my mind

Comment: Google it and see what you come up with; it is very easy to find

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using jQuery you can achieve the desired effect using basic **Event Listeners**. https://jsfiddle.net/gnu9utos/3/

```
// first get the element that we'll be interacting with
var element = document.querySelector('.somediv');

// assuming we managed to successfully get the element from the document
if(element) {
    var before = element.getAttribute('data-imgbefore');
    var after = element.getAttribute('data-imgafter');

    if(before && after) {
        element.style.background = 'url(' + before + ')'; // set the initital state

        element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
            element.style.background = 'url(' + after + ')';
        });

        element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
            element.style.background = 'url(' + before + ')'; 
        });
    }
}
```

<strike>You might want to add a check for `mouseleave` to revert the image back to it's original state</strike> and add a little bit of css.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for! Huge thank to you!

Comment: I've adde more of the divs to simulate future working and it works just for one of the dives... I don't know why

Comment: You'd need to change `document.querySelector` to `document.querySelectorAll`. Which you would then need to loop through and change `element` to be the loop index of the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with this simple JQ

maybe it's not the best solution but it works.i added `background-color` so you can see the change. but you can remove that and leave only `background-image`

see here 
**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1sbatht/1/)**

made 2 variables and assigned them to each image ( before and after img ) to each div with class `.somediv`

add an initial `background-image` to the `div`

then at hover, the `background-image` of the div changes between `imgbefore` and `imgafter`

jq :

```
$(".somediv").each(function(){  

  var imgbef = $(this).data("imgbefore"),
      imgaft = $(this).data("imgafter")
  $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + imgbef + ')','background-color':'red'});

  $(this).hover(function(){

     $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + imgaft + ') ','background-color':'blue'});
  }, function(){
     $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(' + imgbef + ')','background-color':'red'});
  });

});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="somediv" data-imgbefore="img1.png" data-imgafter="img2.png"></div>
```

CSS :

```
.somediv {
   height:250px;
   width:70%;  
 }
```

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the div that you like and change only the data-imgbefore and data-imgafter !!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.somediv').each(function( index, value ) {
  var img = $(this).attr('data-imgbefore');
  $('.somediv').css({'background-image':'url('+ img +')', 'background-size':'200px 200px'});
 });
 
 //$('.somedive').css({'background-image':'url("http://www.palladio-tv.it/Internet/siti_gec/2B/Manzan_Disney/codice/Pippo.png")', 'background-size':'200px 200px'});
 
 $('.somediv').hover(

  function () {
   var img = $(this).attr('data-imgafter');
   $(this).css({'background-image':'url('+ img +')', 'background-size':'200px 200px'});
  }, 

  function () {
   var img = $(this).attr('data-imgbefore');
   $(this).css({'background-image':'url('+ img +')', 'background-size':'200px 200px'});
  }
 );
});
```

```css
.somediv {width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #F2F2F2;border-radius:4px;display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="somediv" data-imgbefore="http://www.palladio-tv.it/Internet/siti_gec/2B/Manzan_Disney/codice/Pippo.png" data-imgafter="http://www.filastrocche.it/contenuti/wp-content/uploads/2001/04/pippogoofy_352.jpg"></div>
<div class="somediv" data-imgbefore="http://www.palladio-tv.it/Internet/siti_gec/2B/Manzan_Disney/codice/Pippo.png" data-imgafter="http://www.filastrocche.it/contenuti/wp-content/uploads/2001/04/pippogoofy_352.jpg"></div>
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that with javascript. You can also add an onmouseleave function, but this time, passing `this.dataset.imgbefore` as second argument.

```js
changebg = function(el, i) {
 var t = "url("+i+")";
 el.style.backgroundImage = t;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="somediv" id="mydiv" data-imgbefore="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" data-imgafter="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals" onmouseover="changebg(this, this.dataset.imgafter)">Lorem</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Why don't you abandon the HTML tag requirement and just try css :hover?

```
#somediv {
    background: url(...);
}

#somediv:hover {
    background: url(...); /* different url */
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: I will need to get those two images from database and echo them right into the HTML tag, because there will be more of those divs and each of them will have its own image